# Hash key issues on facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook to my brand new android application. But I can't make it through the tutorial provided by facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

I tryed to get the haskkey from the provided command :

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Here is the result :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s711ldu1y0aa6xo/screen.png

So I added it to my facebook develloper account as asked in the tutorial but, as it didn't work I tryed to get the hashkey from the following code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

I get the same result meaning my key is the right one... Do you guys know where could the problem be coming from ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s711ldu1y0aa6xo/screen.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This Solution is with code, you have mentioned in your question:**

You are getting the hash-key with debug key... Which may work if you haven't sign the package and running app in debug mode. What you need to do is :

0) Place that code in any of your activity.

1) Go to the manifest file and add to the application android:debuggable="true".

2) Now run your app and monitor the logcat.

3) You will get printed a new key which will be the matching key with x9SLcMXBlgly1f36PJuuc4a3YAc, The key you have got is now having a = sign in the last.

4) Register this key on facbook developer site

**Alternate Trick**

You can do one other thing Simply register this key to the facebook developers site x9SLcMXBlgly1f36PJuuc4a3YAc=

Just add = to the key which is being shown by the facebook app.

you are done!! Hope this will work.

Comment: I'll try this solution, I'll get back to you asap